# Call generic method with generic interface with only one type parameter C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I have this generic method with generic interface:

```
private TP GetSettings<T, TP>( ) where T : IProjectSettings<TP>, new()
    {
        var userSetting = new T();

        return userSetting.DefaultProjectSettings;
    }
```

I have this class inherited from this generic interface:

```
internal class FutureAllowedDaysSettings : IProjectSettings<int>
{
    public string Name => "FutureAllowedDays";
    public int DefaultProjectSettings => 1;
}
```

Generic interface

```
public interface IProjectSettings<T>
{
    string Name { get; }
    T DefaultProjectSettings { get; }
}
```

and now I want to use this method like this:

```
int res = GetSettings<FutureAllowedDaysSettings>();
```

But I can't. I always need to pass the second type like this:

```
int res = GetSettings<FutureAllowedDaysSettings,int>();
```

But it is weird. FutureCheckSettings is IProjectSettings, so the compiler should know that the second type will be int. Because if I try to change bool to int like this:

```
bool int = GetSettings<FutureAllowedDaysSettings,bool>();
```

I'll get the error:
Incorrect number of type parameters

Why it happen and is it possible to call this method passing only one type (FutureAllowedDaysSettings)/ If not how can I change my code to make it possible?

Comment: What would happen if you did `class FutureAllowedDaysSettings : IProjectSettings<int>, IProjectSettings<double>`? How would `GetSettings` know whether it was supposed to return an `int` or a `double`?

Comment: You right. So it is impossible? Only pass IProjectSettings<T> as argument of function? Like `private T GetSettings<T>( IProjectSettings<T> settings )`?

Comment: You either have to specify all the generic types or all the types have to be inferred.